# Get Latest Plugin Version from WP API

Tags: plugins, updates, api

I'm writing a plugin that checks and collects data from WP - including info about installed plugins.

I can get most of the data I require using `get_plugins()` - however, I'd also like to check for the latest repository hosted version of each plugin - but I can't seem to find an API method for this.

Sorry, I've got no code to paste for commenting.. but I've had a good search around - honest!

Where I can find a simple and efficient way to check?

Comment: hi there buddy you have to watchout here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990613/getting-a-list-of-all-plugins
 u gotta give it a try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok - here is a method - thanks to @Rarst for pointing me in the right direction.

Include the require file if the plugins_api function is not found:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'plugins_api' ) ) {
      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php' );
}
```

Then, prepare a query to pass to plugins_api():

```
// set the arguments to get latest info from repository via API ##
$args = array(
    'slug' => 'plugin-slug-name',
    'fields' => array(
        'version' => true,
    )
);

/** Prepare our query */
$call_api = plugins_api( 'plugin_information', $args );

/** Check for Errors & Display the results */
if ( is_wp_error( $call_api ) ) {

    $api_error = $call_api->get_error_message();

} else {

    //echo $call_api; // everything ##

    if ( ! empty( $call_api->version ) ) {

        $version_latest = $call_api->version;

    }

}
```

ref: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/communicating-with-the-wordpress-org-plugin-api/

Comment: The API call is slow and costly - so results should be cached in transients..

Comment: How to get slug name of all plugins

Comment: @SuneelOmrey http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 2):

There is not quite *simple* way to do it, since WP check for plugin updates by submitting all their data in bulk and it's pretty buried in [`wp_update_plugins()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_update_plugins/).

It performs request to `http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/1.1/` API endpoint and gets data about all updates. It's not available as more contained function for individual checks.

You could also look into [Plugin Information API](http://dd32.id.au/projects/wordpressorg-plugin-information-api-docs/) to approach this from repository side.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst - I found the plugins_api function which got me to what I needed..

Comment: hi there - well watch this here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990613/getting-a-list-of-all-plugins
 give it a try buddy